# ASP.NET Security Exception

Tags: .net, asp.net, security, exception

I moved an ASP.NET application from a XP to a new server and now I have this exception:

> 'System.Security.Permissions.SecurityPermission,
>   mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral,

On this line code:

> System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture
>   = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("it-IT");

My server is so configurated:
Windows XP 2003 Sever
SharePoint
MS Visual Studio 2008 Team System Workgroup Server

I tried to change security setting, machine.config.
Someone can help me explain me where and how to change what?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

SharePoint doesn't consider all assemblies in the .NET Framework as safe you just need to add a couple of lines to your web.config file in your application.

Do it in the Sharepoint SafeControls section:

```
<SafeControl Assembly="System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" Namespace="System.Security" TypeName="*" Safe="True" AllowRemoteDesigner="True" />
<SafeControl Assembly="System.Web, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a" Namespace="System.Security.Permissions" TypeName="*" Safe="True" AllowRemoteDesigner="True" />
```

Comment: Thanks, but it's doesn-t work, I tried also to add

<SafeControl Assembly="myassembly" Namespace="System.Security" TypeName="*" Safe="True" AllowRemoteDesigner="True" />

But the exception is the same.